# After in VS2010 include other library, app fail on start with error 0xC000007b

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, libcurl

I have a problem, downloaded curl developemnt package but if i 
add in my visual studio .lib file form this program fail with
0xC000007b on startup.

I trying download all complete source in this i can download simple vs6
project but without errors i convert it to visual studio 2010, i compile
this solution normally, libcurl with curl.exe working good but if i try
add to my project fresh compiled static libcurl library or libcurl dynamic 
library i have this problem and i don't have ideas to debug it.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT, Windows isn't happy about the DLL it needs to load.  That's almost always caused by trying to load a 32-bit DLL in a 64-bit program.  Or a 64-bit in a 32-bit program.  If you converted this VB6 code to VB.NET then you probably need to force it to run in 32-bit mode.  Project + Properties, Compile tab, scroll down, Advanced Compile Options, Target CPU = x86.

Comment: target machine is setted good to x86, what you know other common types of calling this error?

Comment: How exactly did you get libcurl in a VB.NET program?

Comment: sorry i can't test it, have visual studio installed without this language

Answer (score 0):

Install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64) or (x86) depending on architecture of your computer.
It worked for me.